# DatePickerDialog inside AlertDialog (Setting the date on a specific EditText)

Tags: android, datepicker, android-alertdialog

I am new to Android Development and I have been stuck with this problem for days.
I have a fill-in-form implemented with **AlertDialog**. Inside the dialog I create a **DatePickerDialog** and it opens when a specific **EditText** is clicked and focused. I can't seem to figure out how to get the date from the **DatePicker** and show it to the clickable **EditText** afterwards. Below is my code, if anyone has an idea or two please share!!

```
public void AddDialog() {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); 
    LayoutInflater inflater=this.getLayoutInflater();
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_dialog_layout, spinner);
    builder.setView(view);
    Spinner spinner = (Spinner)view.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.list_of_categories, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
    builder.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);

    EditText editText1 = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText4);

    editText1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                SetUpDateDialog();
            }
    });
    editText1.setOnFocusChangeListener(new OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if(hasFocus)
                {
                SetUpDateDialog();
                }


            }
    });

    TextView title = new TextView(this);
    title.setText("Προσθέστε πληροφορίες");
    title.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    title.setPadding(20, 20, 20, 20);
    title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    title.setTextSize(20);
    title.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.add_icon, 0, 0, 0);

    builder.setCustomTitle(title);


    builder.show();
}


public void SetUpDateDialog(){
    new DatePickerDialog(MapActivityPrivilleged.this,d,
            calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
            calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
            .show(); 
}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener d = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month,
            int day) {
        LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(MapActivityPrivilleged.this);
        View view1=li.inflate(R.layout.add_dialog_layout, null);
        EditText editText1 = (EditText)view1.findViewById(R.id.editText4);
        calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
        calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
        editText1.setText(day + "/" + (month+1)+ "/" + year);

        }

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I have found a solution to the problem. I've created a separate **DialogFragment** that uses the current date as the default date in the **picker**.
I have also set a listener on a clickable **EditText** and the fragment is created inside the **onClick()** method.

Once the **dialog** appears, the user can modify the date to his/her choosings.
Finally, with **onDateSet()** I set the user's selected date into a text.

**The Fragment class:**

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
    implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {
        public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            // Use the current date as the default date in the picker

            final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
            int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
            int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


            // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
            return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
            }

            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

                DateText.setText(String.valueOf(day) + "/"
                        + String.valueOf(month + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(year));
                // set selected date into datepicker also

            }
      }
```

Clickable **EditText** and creation of the **DatePickerFragment** inside **onClick()** method.

```
DateText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
DateText.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener () {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                 DialogFragment DateFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
                 DateFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
            }

        });
```